# How do I use the "created_at" timestamp in Twitters API in my iOS app to show seconds/minutes/days since post

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I'm creating a Twitter Client and I call this from the twitter API to get the timestamp for a tweet.

```
NSString *dateString = [twitterDictionary valueForKey:@"created_at"];
cell.dateSinceTweetLabel.text = dateString;
```

Which gives me a date, but in all other twitter clients I use, they show a countdown of seconds since the tweet, then to minutes since the tweet.

Are they creating some sort of timer? I'm just very interested in how this is done because I think it's a key feature to have in my app.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine what they are doing is something similar to

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *tweetCreatedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSTimeInterval dateDifferenceInSeconds = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:tweetCreatedDate];
cell.dateSinceTweetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f seconds ago", dateDifferenceInSeconds];
```

Comment: Awesome let me give this a try and I'll get back.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the difficult part of this question is getting the date in a format other than:

Tue May 20 03:09:05 +0000 2014

There are a number of different answers on this topic all slightly different and most of them seem to be wrong (as in didn't work for me)[This link has loads of answers, all slightly different, with only one working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789702/nsdate-formatter-issue-with-twitter-json-api))

First get the date and change its format to one you want:

```
NSString * createdDate = dict[@"created_at"];

NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z y"];
NSDate * newDate = [df dateFromString:createdDate];
```

This will now get the date in the format: 2014-05-20 03:09:05 +0000 which can be used for comparison

```
NSTimeInterval secondsElapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:newDate];
```

Now we have the seconds different between the two times we can easily calculate the hours, minutes etc:

```
daysDifferent = secondsElapsed/60*60*24
hoursDifferent = secondsElapsed/60*60
minutesDifferent = secondsElapsed/60
secondsDifferent = secondsElapsed/60*60*24
```

You could also calculate the hours, minutes and seconds using modulo (%) but that's easy enough to do on your own ([or you can look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792640/difference-between-two-dates-for-countdown-timer-implementation))